# QRisk calculator

Tags: r, error-handling

I have been using to cvd risk using the QRISK3 package. I am able to the the use the function. However, the output says "<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)".

Can any one help solve this?

I tried all the variables and missing values too, the example dataset works fine

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You'll get a better response if you [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). This means: provide a small representative dataset, all of the relevant code (including required packages) and any error messages - all as plain text, not images.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing is by using the `dput` function on the data or a subset of the data you are using, then pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg